# What is the default enable setting for puppet service resource type?

Tags: puppet

A puppet service is defined like this

```
service { 'some-service':
   ensure     => running,
   hasrestart => true,
   hasstatus  => true,
   require    => [Service['someotherservice'], File['/var/log/somefile']],
 }
```

This does not set a value for `enable`. What is the default value used for `enable`?

The [doc](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/service.html#service-attribute-enable) does not mention what happens if omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, Puppet only manages what you ask it to for a resource.

So if you don't specify a value for the enablement of a service resource, it won't do anything, so the default is to do nothing and not manage that setting.

So it'll not enable it by default, **and** it won't revert the enablement if it's manually enabled.

Comment: Then I need to dig down for the default enable setting for the underlying service manager, systemctl in my case.

Comment: Indeed, it'll reflect what the default state is for the service manager itself